# Can you officially or globally mark a domain as For Sale?

Tags: domains, domain-registration

Domains are ultimately allocated through IANA.  For domains that have been purchased, you can do a WHOIS lookup to get some information on the owner.

If you want to sell a domain, is there any global, official, or semi-official way to mark it as For Sale?  E.G. something you could put into its global WHOIS info?

Comment: You can list it on websites selling domain names. You can change the whois info, and you can put a website at that domain telling that you sell it.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no official way.

One solution would be to make the Technical, Billing or Admin contact name ***FOR SALE*** as a workaround.  But that would rely on someone noticing it.

Comment: Do not do that. Regulations, specifically in ccTLDs, mandates that contact info are legit in the whois, a name such "For Sale" is not legit. You can be imaginative on the address though. Or the nameservers.

Comment: The address is also required to be correct.  So unless one lives on "For Sale St," anything you might list on the address would also be considered a violation.  

There really isn't an official way.  As alternates, he can list the domain in various marketplaces and maybe create a landing page.

Comment: @Dynadot you could easily say c/o in an address or many other tricks, but I basically agree with you and already gave the alternative solutions you list in my comment under the question. Anyway I wanted to say "specifically in gTLDs" in my earlier comment, but many ccTLDs check whois records to, so imagine it as a "standard" in all TLDs, that is easier.